# Array on Declare statements via query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do something like

```sql
DECLARE @ID int = CHANGEME,
        @StartDate  datetime = '2023-09-02 04:00',
        @FinishDate datetime = '2023-09-03 04:00'
```

But this only lets me run this report per id, I have a list of IDs from another table that i can pull by a query

```sql
select id
form table
where tablename like '$tryme$'
```

So is there a way that I can run the report per ID again and again until we've run the list finished?

I saw that this is the way to write multiple/array in the statement

```sql
DECLARE @SITEIDS TABLE(siteid int)
Insert into @SITEIDS
values ('R00013'), ('R00028')
```

but this looks like it's hard coded ids.

I'm trying to get a report with

```sql
DECLARE @ID int = 1,
DECLARE @ID int = 12,
DECLARE @ID int = 123,
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Can you not just do a join? What does it mean to "run the report"?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help

Comment: A typical way to do this would be to use a WHILE loop to add the MIN(Id) into a variable, run the report with that id, and then fill the variable with the next MIN(id) > @id.

Comment: @SchmitzIT A `WHILE` loop is one of the worst ways to do this. A join to `GENERATE_SERIES` or similar might be necessary, but we don't know what OP really wants.

Comment: it's a long discrepancy checker that I would like to run for about 10-50 sites, atm it works if you change the id individually and to save me encoding the ids I can pull them out another table, so it will check all the ids for any errors and show the result per id?

Comment: @Charlieface - I agree that a WHILE loop is not ideal, but at times it would be useful (I use them primarily to replace cursors when dealing with dynamic sql and processing things one-by-one). The wording in the post to run a report per id made me think it would provide the OP with what they were asking for at least.

Comment: Please show the code so we can work out how to incorporate your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should allow you to do exactly what you are asking.

```
DECLARE @id int;

SELECT @id = MIN(id) FROM table where tablename like '$tryme$'

WHILE @id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
   -- Code to run your report here 

   SELECT @id = MIN(id) FROM table WHERE tablename like '$tryme$' AND id > @id
END
```

You put the MIN(id) into your @id variable, process the report for that value, then grab the next MIN(id) that's greater than the one you just processed, and keep looping until no more id value is found.

Answer (score -2):

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2023-09-02 04:00'
DECLARE @FinishDate datetime = '2023-09-03 04:00'

CREATE TABLE #TempIDs (ID int)
INSERT INTO #TempIDs (ID)
    SELECT id FROM YourTable WHERE tablename LIKE '$tryme$'

DECLARE @CurrentID int
SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentID = ID FROM #TempIDs

-- Loop through the IDs and run the report for each ID
WHILE @CurrentID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Execute your report here using @CurrentID



    -- Delete the processed ID from the temporary table
    DELETE FROM #TempIDs WHERE ID = @CurrentID
    -- Get the next ID
    SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentID = ID FROM #TempIDs
END

DROP TABLE #TempIDs
```